# Does Sql Server table partition really can improve the select performance?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, partition

I found the select performance of table partition is lower than the original. Does Sql Server table partition really can improve the select performance? Can anyone can give me some advice?

Comment: What is the point of partitioning? Given that it is part of the mainstream product, I'd suggest that we can infer, its worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Partitioning can help improving your query performance if you are able to work within the limits of how the partition works. Please find more information [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62707/is-table-partitioning-improving-performance-is-it-worth-it).

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning a table using a meaningful partition function enables DBAs to separate hot and cold data, or group all data into different physical disks.

So on your data files, you will have smaller data sizes which can increase performance. Since you have placed your data on separate disks, the SQL Engine can read more data in parallel, thus increasing performance.

Hot-Cold data separation is important, if you can distinguish your data into years for example, and if you don't require previous years too much. Then you can keep current year in a partition on a disk which is faster. Or you can keep active data in memory and cold data in disk based storage.

Comment: Sir, I found two table's inner join take a long time when the dataset is a little bigger. Could you give me some advice about the optimization of inner join?

Comment: You can see the Execution Plan on SSMS if you execute the same query. The execution query can help us to detect which process takes much time and where to concantrate. You can see also the joins there, we might require indexing on those columns. And please check if there is a record in missing indexes system view

Comment: @Eralper -- maybe could you add the other side about how a poorly-planned partition can slow things down?